# How to check if git tag exist via jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins,
In the CI build I would like to check if a specific TAG exist on my git branch

I am trying to use the following plugin

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin

But I am not sure how to operate it

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `execute shell` build step with the following content:

```
gitTagExists=$(git tag -l '$TAGNAME')

if [ -n "$gitTagExists" ]; then
    echo "tag $TAGNAME already exists."
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I never worked on Git client plugin. so others can help you on this.
but using bash shell commands(execute shell) you can get that list of tags and validate it.

tagName=$(git tag -l 'tagstring*')

check the tagName is empty string or not.

hope it would be helpful.